# Is the blastopore imaginary?

Tags: human-biology, embryology

I've been told in my zoology class that the blastopore is an imaginary pore found in gastrula, from which mouth develops first in protostomes and anus develops first in deuterostomes. But we've also been told about the famous blastopore grafting in newts experiment by Spemann-Mangold. So how can you graft something which is imaginary? Is the blastopore really an imaginary pore?

Comment: Ithink they were referring to the fact it is not actually a pore in the normal sense of the word but instead an invagination. It has been imaged many times https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jr-Kai_Yu/publication/6564822/figure/fig2/AS:281320203800598@1444083371979/Figure-2-Expression-of-Nodal-the-Nodal-antagonist-Lefty-and-organizer-related.png

Answer (score 2):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pore):

> Definition of pore
>
> 1 :  a minute opening especially in an animal or plant; especially :  one by which matter passes through a membrane

The blastopore is a real thing, it is not imaginary. It is the point where the mouth or anus eventually develops. I'm guessing the reason your zoology class referred to it as imaginary, however, is probably because it isn't really a *pore* (and *especially* it is *not* a pore into the [blastocoel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blastocoel)). It sort of looks like a pore, but it's just a little indentation (and may even be considered a blastopore before the indent forms); it doesn't really become an opening until later, and the process of gastrulation doesn't actually involve anything going inside the blastopore, it's just a folding in of the cells on themselves.

In summary, I think your understanding is sound, good job, and I just wouldn't get too hung up on the "imaginary" part.